# Java files from jar (generated using gradle task) are not getting accessed in workspace

Tags: java, jar, gradle, gradlew, gradle-eclipse

I am trying to generate java sources from WSDL, package those sources into jar and add that jar into project dependencies.

So far I created jar from wsdl2Java utility of cxf using gradle task (in image bem-1.0.jar) but java files created inside this jar are not getting accessed in workspace !

what I am missing here ?

I see there is slight change in icon of bem-1.0.jar and rest of jar in eclipse build path (highlighted in image below). what does that icon indicate ?

[image]

any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue resolved.

first thing is the icon difference indicate that source in not attached with my jar created.

and when I extracted my jar, it was containing only java source files and missed class files ! including class files worked.